# What are the effects of removing a dual boot on the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, multi-boot, storage

Let's say I have a dual boot on my computer with two linux versions and therefore two partitions on my hard drive.

Is there any potential negative effect from going back to a single boot system by removing one of the existing partitions and extending the remaining partition to the full disk? Especially on the disk itself (e.g. access speed) or performance.

What is happening on the disk when I repartition in this way? And has this anything to do with the filesystem?

Comment: Note: Windows 10 makes more than one partition. If you enabled EFI/UEFI, there's an EFI partition (FAT32), and there may also be a Recovery partition (NTFS). Please click [edit] and advise if you are pondering removing Windows or Linux, as each has their own Boot Manager (GRUB2 for Linux, normally), and you may need to remove the Boot Manager you no longer use, and amend the remaining Boot Manager. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: GRUB will need to be updated, and you could have trouble booting to fix it.  Download a bootable version of the GRUB Repair Utility just in case, and prep it.  Boot the Linux you want to keep.  From there, wipe the other Linux partition(s).  While still in the session, update or reinstall GRUB.  Reusing the other partitions could be complex depending on the situation (where are they? Are you amenable to keeping those as a separate partition or do you need to expand an active one into the space?  etc.).  If you end up needing to reboot and GRUB is still broken, use the GRUB Repair Utility.

Comment: The details will depend on the partition layout and what you want to do with it.  That could be relatively easy or complicated.